# Problems with deploying my first Django app on Azure

Tags: python, django, azure

I have tried different approaches, but none of them works. I still get the:
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for Python==3.9.18`
Or other version I have been trying to use.
I tried:
Installing the version defined in `requirements.txt` with `Set up Python` process:

```
- name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: '3.11.3'
```

(the base version for this app was 3.11.3), changing the `requirements.txt` to match the version that I found from the Action logs in GitHub:
`Python Version: /opt/python/3.9.18/bin/python3.9`

And then checking which version I have installed locally and trying that one (it's 3.10.1). Each time I get the same error but with different version. Please help.

You can browse the full approach here:
https://github.com/JJDabrowski/Portfolio

Comment: Yes I do and I use HTML schema to create my workflow, since I don't use any JS framework in this app

Comment: Did you try removing Python Package in requirements.txt?

Comment: No, not yet. Will try it tommorrow, since I was trying to configure Web App (not static one) for some time now to no avail and need to rest a bit, @PravallikaKV ;P

Comment: You want to deploy only `Shroomcast` folder. Is it?

Comment: Yes I do and the default deployment with Web App didn't do it, since it lead to the whole repo. Will try to configure it later. Learning this from scratch from tomorrow and the docs aren't the clearest TBH, @PravallikaKV

Comment: Ok, I will try to deploy and update if I'm able to.

Comment: Tried your solution with removing Python from `requirements.txt` and it worked, @PravallikaKV (I get some other error now xddd). Please supply it as a response to this question and I will upvote it and mark as the answer.

Comment: I could deploy the project, check the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for Python==3.9.18

To resolve this error, remove `Python` Package in requirements.txt.

**requirements.txt:**

```
Django
requests
```

**Also, to deploy the project which is under subfolder of the repository add command `cd <folder_name>` in the workflow:**

```
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd Shroomcast
          pip install -r requirements.txt
```

---

I could deploy the `Portfolio/Shroomcast` project to Azure App Service by cloning your repository in my environment.

**My GitHub Workflow:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - kpyapppp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd Shroomcast
          pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_B36489908C03429XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX45498D }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_278D0BF75D57425FXXXXXXXXXXXXXC4434 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_6E3C2C39206A4BXXXXXXXXXXX41A }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'kpyapppp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
```

- **Deployed Successfully:**

[image]

Comment: I encountered another problem after deployment though and quickfixes from the web don't work. It would be awesome, if you could check it out @Pravallika KV: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78211700/my-django-azure-app-doesnt-fill-home-site-wwwroot-with-apps-contents

Comment: Can you try creating a seperate repository for `Shroomcast` project and deploy to Azure?

Comment: It works now, thanks a million, @Pravallika KV