# My Django Azure app doesn't fill home/site/wwwroot with app's contents

Tags: django, azure

My Django Azure app doesn't put the app's components in the `home/site/wwwroot` directory. The problem might lie in that I have renamed the main directory of the app as `core`. But I have tried to putting `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 core.wsgi` in `configuration/general settings` and this only broke the app and I found in logs that the module core is non-existant.
I have also put `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = 1` in settings. I still get the start app page instead of my apps' main page.

You can see the code here: https://github.com/JJDabrowski/Portfolio

Are there any ways to view to logs during the deployment to see what happens that my `home/site/wwwroot` doesn't have the app's components inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting my comments from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78210738/19991670) as answer.**

To deploy your [application](https://github.com/JJDabrowski/Portfolio/Shroomcast) and run it without any issues:

- Create a separate repository of your `Portfolio/Shroomcast` project and deploy to Azure App Service instead of deploying subfolder of the repository.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm stuck later in the process too and I wonder if you know about how to deal with Django projects in the later stages too, @Pravallika KV:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78213966/can-i-configure-a-free-web-app-on-azure-with-static-files

If so, please check this out.