# Can I configure a free web app on Azure with static files?

Tags: django, azure

I am trying to deploy my first Django project, but for some reason the static files are not working properly.
When I check out static directory in my `SSH` it shows that the files are in there, but the template doesn't see them.
My settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"
STATIC_URL = "static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "assets"
]
```

I couldn't find anymore answers on stack overflow that would help me so I asked chatGPT and he said that I should create a storage on Azure. When I asked him if there are free storage plans, he said no, but I shouldn't pay much and he forwarded me to pricing calculator which showed $21 for a month.
This app has a funny `static` containing only of `base.css` and a mushroom photo. Should I really pay $21 or even more for it a month?

I wonder if there is any other way than to create a storage or perhaps the pricing in the calculator was wrong.

The code:

https://github.com/JJDabrowski/Shroomcast

Comment: Add this code ```
if  settings.DEBUG:


urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
``` to your url.py of your django app.

Comment: Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/5zilqBB.png).

Comment: Wait, but the DEBUG is set to false in this repo, @AsleshaKantamsetti 

Comment: Run this command ```python manage.py collectstatic```.

Comment: This command runs automatically when deploying on Azure, @AsleshaKantamsetti. I also re-run it and the directory's contents were overwritten, too, but it didn't help.

Comment: Check this link https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/django.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully serve static files in production, I used WhiteNoise and deployed it to Azure App Service.

I used your git repo code and made the necessary changes.

To use whitenoise, I added the lines below in the settings. py file, as shown below:

Note: Add whitenoise middleware after the security middleware.

**settings. py**:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
       'otherInstalledApps
       "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'other middlewares'
    ]


STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"
STATIC_URL = "static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "assets"
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = ('whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage')
```

I added the white noise to the requirements.txt file, as shown below.

**requirements.txt**:

```html
Django==4.2.1
requests==2.31.0
whitenoise==6.6.0
```

I ran the commands below to install whitenoise and collect static files for production.

```
pip install whitenoise   
python manage.py collectstatic 
python manage.py migrate
```

**LocalOutput**:

[image]

It was deployed successfully to azure app service.

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]

Comment: Who's awesome? You're awesome, @Aslesha Kantamsetti :) Thanks!